Synapse notebook access CSV / ZIP files from on premise
I am trying to access different types of files (CSV/ZIP/ ETC...) within my company's on premise shared drives.
As different departments submit their documents, I seek python / pyspark code to fetch these files.
Company procedures wont allow to change and upload them into blob storage.

AFAIK, there is no direct way to load files from local to synapse notebook.

AFAIK, Synapse notebooks are cloud-based environments, so they don't have direct access to your local file system. To work with local files in Synapse notebooks, you'll need to upload them to a cloud storage service like Azure Blob Storage or Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2.
If you don't want to us blob storage your Synapse workspace have Azure Data Lake storage Gen 2 (ADLS) assigned to it, you can use it to first store the data from on-prem shared folders to ADLS account and after that you can fetch the files from ADLS account to Synapse notebook.
You can use synapse pipeline to load data from on-prem to ADLS using file System linked service with SHIR which copy files from on-prem.
